# Running program with g++ compiler on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I need help with running my program on Ubuntu. I have two cpp files and a header file.
I get the following error. Can someone help me please.

```
gopy@gopy-VPCEB36GM:~/Desktop/helo$ g++ -c Sequence.cpp
gopy@gopy-VPCEB36GM:~/Desktop/helo$ g++ -c SequenceTest.cpp
gopy@gopy-VPCEB36GM:~/Desktop/helo$ g++ -o Sequence.o SequenceTest.o test
g++: error: test: No such file or directory
```

The o files are created when I open the helo folder

Comment: Also the compiler is GCC, Gnu C(++) Compiler

Comment: Yeah I have the two o files

Comment: I would recommend makefiles.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) for a thorough introduction to gcc/g++.

Answer (score 3):

g++ man

```
-o <file>                Place the output into <file>
```

means test must be right after the -o flag, otherwise linker thinks test is the input

```
gopy@gopy-VPCEB36GM:~/Desktop/helo$ g++ -o test Sequence.o SequenceTest.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
g++ -o test Sequence.o SequenceTest.o
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `-o` stands for output file name. In this case, g++ assumes `Sequence.o` as the output file name, `SequenceTest.o` and `test` are the files to be compiled or linked. So

```
g++ -o test Sequence.o SequenceTest.o
```

is the right way to do this. And, you can do the whole compilation process with a single command.

```
g++ Sequence*.cpp -o test
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-answer is 'sudo apt-get codeblocks'. You can spend more time learning C++, and less time mucking with command lines.